# how to get current component in request interceptor

Tags: angular, angular5, interceptor

I'm devoloping an application with symfony / angular5.
I want to get the current activated component on my requestInterceptor.
this is my interceptor

```
 import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
    import {
      HttpEvent,
      HttpInterceptor,
      HttpHandler,
      HttpRequest,
      HttpErrorResponse
    } from '@angular/common/http';

    import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import { TokenService } from './token.service';


    import { AuthenticationService } from './authentication.service';
    import { retry } from 'rxjs/operators';
    import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

    @Injectable()
    export class RequestInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

      constructor(
        private tokenService: TokenService,
        private injector: Injector

      ) { }

      intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        let loggedUser: any = this.getLoggedUser();
        let options: any = {};

        if (this.isApiRequest(req.url)) {

          options.setParams = {
            selectedOrganization: loggedUser.selectedOrganizationId,
            selectedOrganizationType: loggedUser.selectedOrganizationTypeId
          };


          options.setHeaders = { Authorization: `Bearer ${this.tokenService.getAccessToken()}` };
          console.log('secured');
          return this.execute(req, next, options)

        }
        else {
          console.log('unsecured');
          return this.execute(req, next, null).retry(1)
        }

      }

      protected isApiRequest(url) {
        return url.startsWith(environment.server_api);
      }

      private getLoggedUser() {
        return this.injector.get(AuthenticationService).getUserFromStorage();
      }

      protected execute(req, next, options = null): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        const authReq = (options !== null) ? req.clone(options) : req.clone();
        console.log(authReq.url);
        return next.handle(authReq)
          .catch((err: any, caught) => {
            if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
              if (err.status === 403) {
                console.info('err.error =', err.error, ';');
              }
              if (err.status === 401) {

                return this.injector.get(AuthenticationService).refreshToken().subscribe(
                  (res) => {

                    const authReq = req.clone(options.setHeaders = { Authorization: `Bearer ${this.tokenService.getAccessToken()}` });

                   // here i have to re-init current component 
                  }
                )
              }


              return Observable.throw(err);
            }
          });
      }
    }
```

and this is my component

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatSelect } from '@angular/material';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { AuthenticationService } from '../../../services/authentication.service';
import { DataService } from '../../../services/data.service';

import { Constants } from '../../../constant/constants';
import { CoreUserAdditional } from '../../../models/core-user-additional.model';

import { CoreOrganization } from '../../../models/all';
import { Functions } from '../../../common/helpers/functions';
import { PasswordValidation } from "../../../common/validators/Password-validation";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-user-additional',
  templateUrl: './create-user-additional.component.html'
})
export class CreateUserAdditionalComponent {

  spinnerstate: boolean = false;
  coreUserAdditional = new CoreUserAdditional();
  form: FormGroup
  coreOrganizations: any[] = []
  coreAgencies: any[] = []
  organizationTypes: any[] = []
  organizationNames: any[] = []
  organizationIds: any[] = []
  dis: boolean

  selectedCoreOrganization

  civilities: string[] = [
    new Constants().CIVILITY_MR,
    new Constants().CIVILITY_MS,
    new Constants().CIVILITY_MRS
  ]

  // Event fired after view is initialized
  @ViewChild('organizations') organizations: MatSelect
  @ViewChild('roles') roles: MatSelect

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private dataService: DataService,
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
    private router: Router,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      civility: [null, Validators.required],
      firstName: [null, Validators.required],
      lastName: [null, Validators.required],
      email: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.email])],
      password: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)])],
      confirmPassword: [null, Validators.required],
      function: [null],
      phone: [null],
      coreOrganizations: [null, Validators.required],
      coreAgencies: [null, Validators.required],
      coreRoles: [null, Validators.required]
    }, {
      validator: PasswordValidation.MatchPassword // your validation method
      }
    );
    let loggedUser = this.authenticationService.getUserFromStorage()

    this.spinnerstate = true;
    this.dataService.getCollection(new CoreOrganization(), '/get_for_new_user').subscribe(
      (response) => {
        if (loggedUser.selectedOrganizationId === null)
        {
          this.coreOrganizations = response.getMember()
          this.spinnerstate = false;
        }
        else {
          this.coreOrganizations.push(response)
          this.selectedCoreOrganization = response
          this.spinnerstate = false;
        }

      });

  }
}
```

on my component i'm doing something on subscribe. so i have to re-init component after refrshing token.

> how cant i do it.
>    my goal is to reInit the current component.

Comment: Can you show the trimmed down relevant code of your component and interceptor? You probably have to `subscribe` from the component and restart itself right from there. Some more background on the problem is also appreciated, the actual problem will give better answers than an attempted solution.

Comment: question updated

Comment: How would you `reinit` the current component? You will probably need a `window.location.reload()` if `401` is coming from a service call. Another way is to navigate to the current route by injecting router and using `NavigationEnd` in your component to make it reloadable. If `401` is coming from a page request, it should also have the `Location` header set which you can use to redirect after authentication. I don't think there is an easy way to get component in interceptor, and also doesn't think that would be a good idea. I may be wrong.

Comment: I'm calculating the token delay before starting the request. The problem is when refreshing app component ( F5 ). i 'm having to requestes in the same time. the refresh request and the component request(with the old token). in this cas i'm having 401 error